# Enabling public access to SQL Server in Azure devops release pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

In order to run migrations on my Test Azure SQL which is configured with PrivateLink I temporarly enable public access and then disable it again.

```
Set-AzSqlServer
  -ServerName $sqlServerName
  -ResourceGroupName $(IntegrationResourceGroupName)
  -PublicNetworkAccess "Enabled"
```

And it worked for months, but recently I started receiving this error message.

```
Cannot find the Azure Active Directory object 'My_DB_Admins_Group_Name'.
Please make sure that the user or group or application you are authorizing is registered
in the current subscription's Azure Active directory. To get a list of Azure Active Directory
groups use Get-AzADGroup, or to get a list of Azure Active Directory
users use Get-AzADUser or to get a list of Azure Active Directory applications use Get-AzADApplication.
```

Release pipeline was not modified. What might be the reason?

I can execute this PS command from my local machine, as me, and it works fine.

Comment: Was the pipeline identify part db_owner on the AzSQL and were there any changes on AzSql redeployment in between? May be you are part of the AAD owner group which could be the reason it is working from local machine. I quickly looked and found [this link](https://erikej.github.io/sqlserver/2021/01/25/azure-sql-advanced-deployment-part3.html) explaining how to but not why!

Comment: No it was never. But error here seems to be related to Azure Ad. "My_DB_Admins_Group_Name" group mentioned in error is group containing Database Administrators. I don't know why it's mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message : Only azaduser and azadgroup are filtered by azsqlserveractivedirectoryadministrator. It is unlikely that it will look for service principles. You might make an azure ad group called dbas or something similar. To that group, then add the service principal to it.

Then add the group to the sql server using that set-azsqlcommand

```
    $sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "theserviceprincipalname"
Add-AzADGroupMember -MemberObjectId $($sp.id) -TargetGroupDisplayName "AAD Group Name"

Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName 'data-eastus2'  -ServerName 'data-eastus2-sqlsvr' -DisplayName "AAD Group Name"
```

Comment: Then how did it work before? Set-AzSqlServer with -SqlAdminPassword also doesn't work. But it should right?

Comment: yes, absolutely true, could you please try adding  for now and retry as previously it didn't throw an error but now it is, and could you please check if there were any change in permissions under AAD or somewhere related to applications

Comment: Added service principal to database administrators group and it didn't help